# CanActivate wait and take from store

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I have next method in my class which implements from CanActivate:

```
export class CanActivateLoginedInforamtion implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private store: Store<AppState>) {}

  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean>{
    return timer(10000).pipe(
      () => this.store.select(({ user: { loginState }}) => {          
        console.log(loginState); 
        return loginState === 'LOGINED' 
      })
    );
  }
}
```

But, my store.select returning instantly and not waiting ten seconds, why?

When used promise:

```js
export class CanActivateLoginedInforamtion implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private store: Store<AppState>) {}

  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Promise<boolean>{
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      this.store.select(({ user: { loginState }}) => { 
        console.log(loginState); resolve(loginState === 'LOGINED');
      })
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? This is not how you use observable pipes.

Comment: But what are you trying to achieve? You want to wait 10 seconds before calling your store?

Comment: And what does `this.store.select` return? An observable?

Comment: I'm even more confused now than I was before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the observable equivalent to your promise based example:

```js
export class CanActivateLoginedInforamtion implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private store: Store<AppState>) {}

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, 
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.isLoggedIn();
  }

  private isLoggedIn(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.store.select(({ user: { loginState }}) => {          
      return loginState === 'LOGINED';
    });
  }
}
```

`this.store.select()` is returning `Observable<boolean>`, so you can simply return that from `canActivate`. I have moved the store query to a new function to hopefully make it a little clearer.

If, for some reason, you want to wait 10 seconds before making the call, you can query your store after `timer` has elapsed using `switchMap` in the pipe. This is equivalent to chaining promises.

You will also need to use `take(1)` to limit the number of timer events you want to receive.

```js
export class CanActivateLoginedInforamtion implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private store: Store<AppState>) {}

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, 
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean> {
    return timer(10000).pipe(
      take(1),
      switchMap(() => this.isLoggedIn())
    );
  }

  private isLoggedIn(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.store.select(({ user: { loginState }}) => {          
      return loginState === 'LOGINED';
    });
  }
}
```